# Chrome DevTools Protocol: `Network.setCookie({ sameSite: 'None' })` fails, why?

Tags: cookies, samesite, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm having an issue where the Chrome DevTools Protocol returns `{ success: false }` when sending a `Network.setCookie` request with `sameSite` set to `"None"`.

What could the issue be? `"Lax"` and `"Strict"` appear to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sameSite` can only be set to `"None"` on a secure cookie. Try passing `{ sameSite: "None", secure: true }`.

More info on `SameSite=None`: https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/#changes-to-the-default-behavior-without-samesite